# Getting random entry from Objectify entity

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

How can I get a random element out of a Google App Engine datastore using [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine)? Should I fetch all of an entity's keys and choose randomly from them or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Assign a random number between 0 and 1 to each entity when you store it. To fetch a random record, generate another random number between 0 and 1, and query for the smallest entity with a random value greater than that.

Comment: Not a bad idea, though it sounds like I'd be creating an index solely for the purpose of selecting data, which seems unfortunate. My table will be updated only infrequently, so I'm thinking about locally caching the list of keys and then grabbing one randomly (avoiding an extra column / index / query).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch all.
For example:

1. countall = query(X.class).count() 
   // http://groups.google.com/group/objectify-appengine/browse_frm/thread/3678cf34bb15d34d/82298e615691d6c5?lnk=gst&q=count#82298e615691d6c5
2. rnd = Generate random number [0..countall]
3. ofy.query(X.class).order("- date").limit(rnd); //for example -date or some chronic indexed field
4. Last id is your...
   (in average you fatch 50% or at lest first read is in average 50% less)

Improvements (to have smaller key table in cache)!

After first read remember every X elements.
Cache id-s and their position. So next time query condition from selected id further (max ".limit(rnd%X)" will be X-1).

Random is just random, if it doesn't need to be close to 100% fair, speculate chronic field value (for example if you have 1000 records in 10 days, for random 501 select second element greater than fifth day).

Other options, if you have chronic field date (or similar), fetch elements older than random date and younger then random date + 1 (you need to know first date and last date). Second select random between fetched records. If query is empty select greater than etc...

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/objectify-appengine/KTdqgSU-MU0) about selecting some random elements from an Objectified datastore:

> If your ids are sequential, one way would be to randomly select 5
>   numbers from the id range known to be in use. Then use a query with an
>   "in" filter().
>
> If you don't mind the 5 entries being adjacent, you can use count(),
>   limit(), and offset() to randomly find a block of 5 entries.
>
> Otherwise, you'll probably need to use limit() and offset() to
>   randomly select one entry out at a time.
>
> -- Josh

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much adapt the algorithm provided Matejc.  However, 3 things:

1. Instead of using count() or the datastore service factory (DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService()), I have an entity that keep track of the total count of the entities that I am interested in.  The reason for this approach is that:
   a. count() could be expensive when you are dealing with a lot of objects
   b. You can't test the datastore service factory locally...testing in prod is just a bad practice.
2. Generating the random number: ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, maxRange)
3. Instead of using limit(), I use offset, so I don't have to worry about "sorting."